# How do I trigger TCM (TTL convert to Manual) on a Godox XPro II?

Tags: off-camera-flash, godox, ttl, settings

I've owned a Godox XPro transmitter before, but now I've upgraded to the newer XPro II. And it doesn't have a TCM button. The specs say it does TCM and there's a TCM C.Fn for setting the type of light I'm using. But I can't find anything in the manual about how to actually trigger TCM to convert the TTL-set power level to an M setting.  What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Godox simplified the function. Instead of holding down a TCM button for 2 seconds, all you need to do is change the mode for the Group from TTL to M (like on a Profoto Air). The basic steps are:

1. Set a group to TTL.
2. Take a photo.
3. Select the Group button.
4. Tap the Mode button to switch from TTL to M.

The power setting that was used in TTL is now a Manual power setting.

See also: [the StrobePro XPro II walkthrough](https://youtu.be/BLA1sMbUfpg?t=2994) on youtube.

Comment: That's pretty cool to know. I think I'll stick with my vintage Flashpoint "R2 Pro Mark II" version that has the A-B-C-D-E group buttons around the circle/set switch at the bottom, though. Too much muscle memory to try and retrain my fingers to use the buttons up and down the upper left side.

Comment: On the other hand, if you want to go from TTL back to a previously set Manual power setting without using TCM, that could be a real drag that it changes the Manual power setting from where you left it the last time you used Manual power.

Comment: @MichaelC, Not really. The Xpro II also lets you save/load user presets for those configurations you use all the time. :)

Answer (score -1):

The response that mentions selecting the group and changing it from TTL to Manual is not accurate. I have just tested that method and it doesn’t work that way. Also, the response doesn’t make sense because it would limit you from being able to keep an intentional power setting in manual mode, while being able to let the camera choose via TTL when you want it to. I’m guessing there is no TCM function, and that’s why this trigger is branded as X2T and does not include a “Pro” designation like the other triggers that offer this feature. I could be wrong about the TCM not being a part of the X2T’s feature set, but I am not wrong that the method described where you take a shot in TTL and then toggle to manual mode does not work.

Comment: This Q&A is only about the [Godox **XPro II** transmitter](https://www.godox.com/product-a/XPro-II.html). The X2T is a completely different model and has no TCM capability.